# Find Next File in Folder based on Name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder with files, all named by date. I have the file name (date) that I'm looking for, in cell `E2`. The cell has already been formatted so that it's in the same format as the file names. Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub Step2Importsheet()

Sheets.Add Type:= _
"E:\MyFolder\Manipulated Data\Test\" & Range("E2").Text & ".csv"

End Sub
```

This code works great if the date in cell `E2` exists as a file in the folder.

Now here's my problem: In some cases, I have a date listed in `E2` that does not exist as a file in the folder. I want to expand the code so that if it doesn't exist, it looks for the next sequential date until it finds a file. (In most cases this will be one or two dates after the date in `E2` but it might go as far as five days out. It will never hit an indefinite loop).

Appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Use the `Dir` Function - it accepts wildcards, and you can then step thru each file in the folder. If you need to check the actual file date, you can use a FileSystemObject - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function

Comment: That code can't work. The `Type` argument of `Sheets.Add` needs to be an [`XlSheetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlsheettype) enum value, not a file/path... at least as far as [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.add) goes.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon works very well. Been using it for about 5 months now. Never had an issue (as long as the file name exists)

Comment: @braX I'd like to automate it. I don't want to have to step through the files myself.

Comment: Ah, missed that part "If you are inserting a sheet based on an existing template, specify the path to the template"

Comment: @Gitty I think what braX meant is that you can pair `Dir` with a loop to find the next file.

Comment: The `Dir` function will help you automate it - by "step" i meant "loop" - it's automatic

Comment: `Dim dtTest As Date

dtTest = Range("E2").Text

Do Until Dir("E:\MyFolder\Manipulated Data\Test\" & dtTest & ".csv") <> ""
    dtTest = dtTest + 1
Loop

Sheets.Add Type:="E:\MyFolder\Manipulated Data\Test\" & dtTest & ".csv"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone! The code below works well. I had to use `Range` instead of `Date` because I had to convert it to `Text` for it to be able to work as a file name.

```
Dim newdate As Range
Set newdate = Range("E2")
Do Until Dir("E:\MyFolder\Manipulated Data\Test\" & newdate.Text & ".csv") <> vbNullString
newdate = newdate + 1
Loop
Sheets.Add Type:="E:\MyFolder\Manipulated Data\Test\" & newdate.Text & ".csv"
```

Comment: Suggest you use the `.Value2` property and the `Format` function instead of the `.Text` property.  The `.Text` property is easily changed.  And if the column width gets narrowed, it may return only `###` instead of the date. But using `Format(newdate.Value2,"your_required_date_format")` should be more bulletproof.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub LookForFile()
    Dim sBaseFolder As String
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim datFileName As Date

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("FileSystemObject")
    sBaseFolder = "E:\MyFolder\Manipulated Data\Test\"

    ' Initalize date
    datFileName = CDate(Range("E2"))

    Do While Not objFSO.FileExists(sBaseFolder & GetFileNameFromDate(datFileName) & ".csv")

        datFileName = DateAdd("d", 1, datFileName)

        ' Maybe place a limit here in case file doesn't exist

    Loop

    ' datFileName should now contain the date of a matching file

End Sub

Function GetFileNameFromDate(ByVal p_date As Date)
    ' Returns YY-MM-DD format
    GetFileNameFromDate = Year(p_date) & "-" & Right("0" & Month(p_date), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & Day(p_date), 2)
End Function
```

The `GetFileNameFromDate` function lets you specify the file name format since I imagine it's not a direct date but probably a string with the slashes removed.